# Can you somehow make a game(not ui) like, 30 % darker without having to recolor every sprite in unity 2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

so basically i made some pixel-art for my game, but i realized that it was way too bright, and i am trying to make a game in a more darker tone, and now i dont feel like recoloring every single one of my sprites, so can i just make the game a bit darker somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely could do that using Unity's Post-Processing **Auto Exposure** which is a way to adjust the global brightness of the game's scene.

1. Download the Post-processing package from Package Manager.
2. Add the Post-process Volume component to your camera.
3. You will find a **New** button to create a Profile for that volume.
4. Finally, add Auto Exposure as an Effect Override and play with values!

**Note:** If you're using URP or HDRP pipelines you don't need to download the Post-Processing package from Package Manager since it's integrated by default and I think it's called **Global Volume**.

If you have any other question, please don't hesitate to ask!